# Tailwind CSS applying both pseudo class (e.g: hover OR active) in class name

Tags: tailwind-css

How do I not duplicate same code for hover and active,
when same effect is wanted for both of them

**active OR hover:bg-primary**

I tried

> hover:active:bg-primary

,
and it only works for active soo..
I'm guessing putting them together makes it to an "AND" condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own class with these tailwindcss parameters 
something like that

```
.hover-active-bg-primary {
  @apply hover:bg-primary active:bg-primary
}
```